# Transferring Keynote to Youtube or Quicktime with delay in music and timing of slides

Tags: keynote, quicktime, youtube, slideshow

I am having a problem when I transfer my keynote project to Youtube or Quicktime. The slides don't change at the time I designed it in Keynote and my song only plays on the first slide when transferred eventhough in keynote I designed it to play for all of the songs.  In keynote it plays perfectly but when I transfer to these other programs, it just isn't working right.  Any insights? and or directions to fix this issue?

Thank you
Dawn

Answer (score 1):

When exporting a **Keynote** prevention to video, be sure first to set all transitions to the timing that you wish.  All *click* events will be set to the defaults in the dialog shown below.  Change this to `0 seconds` for timing and export again.  By working between the timing of your automatic transitions (usually the length of your song) along with looking at your click transitions, you should be able to get the timing right.

[image: Export Keynote to Quicktime]